# Como colocar variável dentro de aspas no javascript?

Tags: javascript, variáveis, array

Preciso fazer com quê esse código funcione. Mas sempre que coloco a variável no lugar ou dentro das "" não funciona.

```
//jvectormap data
var visitorsData = {
"US": 398, //USA
"SA": 400, //Saudi Arabia
"CA": 1000, //Canada
"DE": 500, //Germany
"FR": 760, //France
"CN": 300, //China
"AU": 700, //Australia
"BR": (TOTAL_VISIT_PAIS), //Brazil
"IN": 800, //India
"GB": 320, //Great Britain
"RU": 3000 //Russia
};`
```

Queria que ficasse mais ou menos assim:

```
//jvectormap data
var visitorsData = {
"US": 398, //USA
"SA": 400, //Saudi Arabia
"CA": 1000, //Canada
"DE": 500, //Germany
"FR": 760, //France
"CN": 300, //China
"AU": 700, //Australia
(CODE_PAIS): (TOTAL_VISIT_PAIS), //Brazil
"IN": 800, //India
"GB": 320, //Great Britain
"RU": 3000 //Russia
};`
```

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda. :)

Comment: Já experimentaste `visitorsData[CODE_PAIS] = TOTAL_VISIT_PAIS;`?

Comment: Li o [teu comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99631/como-colocar-vari%c3%a1vel-dentro-de-aspas-no-javascript#comment202738_99634), então queres acrescentar ao objeto `visitorsData` dados que vêm do PHP é isso?

Comment: Ou queres acrescentar dados a esse objeto no PHP diretamente?

Comment: E esse código JS que tens na pergunta é feito no PHP? podias pôr um loop no PHP a criar essas propriedades. Ou seja lendo da BD fazer algo como `js.= $chave.': '.$valor.',';` É isso que queres? nesse caso mostra parte do PHP para poder dar-te um exemplo mais concreto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da seguinte forma abaixo, colocando a variável dentro [ ], sem necessidade de colocar aspas:

```
var TOTAL_VISIT_PAIS = '1111';

//jvectormap data
var visitorsData = {
"US": 398, //USA
"SA": 400, //Saudi Arabia
"CA": 1000, //Canada
"DE": 500, //Germany
"FR": 760, //France
"CN": 300, //China
"AU": 700, //Australia
"BR": TOTAL_VISIT_PAIS, //Brazil
"IN": 800, //India
"GB": 320, //Great Britain
"RU": 3000 //Russia
};

var CODE_PAIS = "BR";
var TOTAL_VISIT_PAIS = 111;

var visitorsData = {
"US": 398, //USA
"SA": 400, //Saudi Arabia
"CA": 1000, //Canada
"DE": 500, //Germany
"FR": 760, //France
"CN": 300, //China
"AU": 700, //Australia
[CODE_PAIS]: TOTAL_VISIT_PAIS, //Brazil
"IN": 800, //India
"GB": 320, //Great Britain
"RU": 3000 //Russia
};
```

Percorrendo os itens do vetor com foreach:

```
for (var item in visitorsData) {
    console.log(visitorsData[item]);
}
```

**Obs.:** Quando a variável é do tipo String não tem a necessidade de colocar as aspas, pois o Javascript já reconhece como tendo, por ser do tipo String onde na atribuição da variável ela é colocada:

Comment: Já tentei dessa forma. A variável TOTAL_VISIT_PAI funciona normal, mas a CODE_PAIS não.

Comment: Coloca a variável CODE_PAIS dentro de [], conforme eu editei o código.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente cara. Muito obrigadoooo.. :D

Comment: Só mais um pergunta. como faço para realizar um loop nesse codigo.
Tipo:

  //jvectormap data
  var visitorsData = {
   if (var i=0; i < 10; i++){
    [CODE_PAIS_VISIT]: i, //Brasil
   }
  };

Obs: O código acima não funcionou.

Comment: Da seguinte forma:

for (var item in visitorsData ) console.log(visitorsData[item]);

Comment: Mas desse jeito que falaste funciona da mesma forma como o código abaixo?
  `//jvectormap data`  
  `var visitorsData = {` 
  `if (var i=0; i < 10; i++){` 
    `for (i < 10){`
   `[CODE_PAIS_VISIT]: i, //Brasil`
   `}else{[CODE_PAIS_VISIT]: i//Brasil}`
 `} `
  `};`

Comment: Não, da forma que eu falei ele percorre item por item na variável visitorsData.

Comment: Então de que forma faço para realizar loop de um item dentro da variável visitorsData?

Comment: Você pode acesso o valor diretamente sem loop assim por exemplo: visitorsData['FR']

Comment: @PabloMarconyF `[CODE_PAIS]: TOTAL_VISIT_PAIS,` não vai funcionar no Internet Explorer nem noutros browsers menos modernos.

Comment: Vou explicar como funciona o sistema para que você possa me ajuda. 
Tenho uma pagina index.php. Nela tem um loop que coleta linha por linha da tabela infor_visit do banco de dados e insere nas variáveis que são enviadas pro arquivo dashboard.js onde tem o código acima.

Comment: O que eu quero é que a variável visitorsData armazene a mesma quantidade de linha e informações que tem na minha tabela.  
  OBS: A quantidade de linhas no banco de dados não é fixa.

Comment: @PabloMarconyF Se você possui dúvidas adicionais, não relacionadas à pergunta atual, por favor faça novas perguntas. Evite discussões extensas nos comentários.